# Merge lists in specific order

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list of lists and i want to merge the lists with an specific order. See example:

```
id list  0         1           2
       [[0], [2, 6, 1, 4], [3, 7, 5]]

  Order          Resulting List
[1, 0, 2] = [2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5]
[0, 2, 1] = [0, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4]
[2, 1, 0] = [3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0]
```

Someone can suggest a more elegant algorithm that proposed below?

```
    groups = [[0], [2, 6, 1, 4], [3, 7, 5]]
    orders = [[1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]

    for order in orders:
        LC = []
        for i in order:
            LC += groups[i]
    return LC
```

Let me explain a bit better what I need:

```
groups = [[0], [2, 6, 1, 4], [3, 7, 5]] 
orders = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]] # Order of each group in LC
solutions = [] # I want to put the created LC here
for order in orders:
    LC = [] # I need this because a want LCs individualy and not one with all 
    for i in order: # for each order I pick de index (i) of the group
         LC += grupos[i] # and merge then according with index of group
        solutions.append([LC])
    print(solutions)
```

I want this (one LC for each order):

```
[[0, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4], [2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5], [3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0]]
```

and not this:

```
[0, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0]
```

The algorithm above works, but a need a another one more elegant and efficient.

Some examples of output:

```
groups = [[0], [2, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4], [6]]

Order = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
LC = [2, 1, 0, 3, 7, 5, 4, 6]

    [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
    [3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 6]

    [3, 1, 2, 0, 4]
    [4, 2, 1, 3, 7, 5, 0, 6]

    [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]
    [6, 2, 1, 3, 7, 5, 4, 0]

    [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    [0, 3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]

    [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]
    [0, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 6]

    [0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
    [0, 6, 3, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1]

    [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
    [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6]

    [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]
    [0, 2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5]

    [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
    [0, 2, 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to work. You create a new LC per iteration only returning the last one. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: Works in my machine, I put below the output. The list "solutions" store all LC created.

Comment: Your initial code is not the same as your edited code.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is basically identical to the one you proposed, but more Python-esque, using a list comprehension.

```
>>> def merge_lists(desired_order):
...     merged_list = [element for i in desired_order for element in parts[i]]
...     return merged_list
... 
>>> desired_order = orders[0]
>>> merge_lists(desired_order)
[2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some other technique like a comprehension. The following will return a flat list:

```
return [part for order in orders for i in order for part in parts[i]]
```

And the following will return a 2D list:

```
return [[part for i in order for part in parts[i]] for order in orders]
```

Comment: Extending a list is pretty efficient.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Once, sure, but it has to create new lists each time, so doing it repeatedly isn't the best (same reason `sum(lists, [])` is generally avoided).

Comment: You are confusing `l = l + some_list` and `l += some_list` both do very different things. `l += some_list` is exactly the same as `l.extend(some_list)`. If the OP had correct code LC would be created outside all the loops and just extended each time.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Oh yeah, `list.extend` on the same list vs assigning a new list, right. I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just call itertools.chain on the indexes and combine with  with *operator.itemgetter*:

```
 frIn [9]: groups = [[0], [2, 6, 1, 4], [3, 7, 5]]

In [10]: orders = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]] # Ord

In [11]: from itertools import chain

In [12]: from operator import itemgetter


In [13]: [list(chain(*itemgetter(*o)(groups))) for o in orders]
    [[0, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4], [2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5], [3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0]]
```

In you own code, you only return the last LC so it could not work correctly:

```
for order in orders:
    LC = []  # overwritten each iteration so you only get the last sublists.
    for i in order:
        LC += parts[i]
return LC
```

Comment: Its because i need the LCs individual, not a single list with all of them.

Comment: @RafaelFrinhani, your code still only returns the last one you create so it could not possibly do what you want.

Comment: Hi mr Cunningham, I put more information im my question to better clarify what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7]]
orders = [[0,1,2], [2,1,0]]

result = [input_element for order in orders for order_element in order for input_element in inputs[order_element]]
print(result)
```

Comment: Why are you importing `reduce` if you are not using it?

Comment: @vishes_shell grabbed an unwanted line :)